# Calculation percentage of my data for different number ranges

Tags: python

I am trying to find out how to calculate percentage of my data for different number ranges. So I have a data that looks like this:

```
0.81761
0.255319
0.359551
0.210191
0.374046
0.188406
0.179487
0.265152
0.207792
0.202614
0.150943
```

..and I have these ranges:

```
0-0.3
0.3-0.7
0.7-1
```

I want to know out of my data, what is the percentage that fall into a specific number range. So, for example:

```
0-0.3 -> 72.7%
0.3-0.7 -> 18.18%
0.7-1 -> 9.09%
```

Does anybody knows how to do this calculation?

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/numpy/numpy_histogram_using_matplotlib.htm

Comment: "Does anybody knows how to do this calculation?" Office calc would be the tool to use.

Comment: @steeldriver Thanks for this, but I actually can't find here how to produce percentage for specific number range. I already did make frequency distribution and histograms in excel. What I care is not graph at this point but only a raw number of the percentage within a specific number range.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `histogram` function from `numpy`

Ex.

```
$ python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 12 2018, 14:36:49)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
>>> import numpy as np
>>>
>>> data = np.loadtxt('datafile')
>>> hist = np.histogram(data,[0,0.3,0.7,1.0])
>>> print 100.0 * hist[0]/sum(hist[0])
[ 72.72727273  18.18181818   9.09090909]
>>>
```

See for example [NumPy - Histogram Using Matplotlib](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/numpy/numpy_histogram_using_matplotlib.htm) (of course, you don't have to plot the result).

Comment: This is far more elegant as my awk solution ;-)

Comment: @RoVo I guess it's like the proverbial swan - `numpy` is paddling furiously beneath the surface ;)

Answer (score 5):

Using `awk`:

```
awk '
    # Count occurencies
    {
    if ($1 < 0.3) a++
    else if ($1 > 0.7) c++
    else b++
    }
    # Print Percentage of count/NR (num records)
    END {
        printf "< 0.3: %.2f%%\n",a/NR*100
        printf "> 0.3 and < 0.7: %.2f%%\n",b/NR*100
        printf "> 0.7: %.2f%%\n",c/NR*100

    }
' file
```